# Sudoku algorithm java- what's with this output?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, logic, sudoku

Just wondering why the following code

```
public static void generateSudoku(int[][] num) {
    boolean[][][] possibilities = new boolean[9][9][9];
    boolean[] noPossibilities = {false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    boolean[] defaultPossibilities = {true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true};
    //Get possibilities
    for( int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
        for( int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(definite[i][j] == 0) {
                possibilities[i][j] = defaultPossibilities;
                for(int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {
                    if(definite[x][j] != 0) {
                        possibilities[i][j][definite[x][j]-1] = false;
                    }
                }
                for(int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
                    if(definite[i][y] != 0) {
                        possibilities[i][j][definite[i][y]-1] = false;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                possibilities[i][j] = noPossibilities;
            }
            System.out.println(possibilities[i][j][0] +" "+ possibilities[i][j][1] +" "+ possibilities[i][j][2] +" "+
                    possibilities[i][j][3] +" "+possibilities[i][j][4] +" "+possibilities[i][j][5] +" "+
                    possibilities[i][j][6] +" "+possibilities[i][j][7] +" "+possibilities[i][j][8]);
        }
    }
}
```

is returning

```
false false false false false false false false false
false false true true true true true true true
false false false true true true true true true
false false false false true true true true true
false false false false false true true true true
false false false false false false true true true
false false false false false false false true true
false false false false false false false false true
false false false false false false false false false
false false false false false false false false false
//etc... (all false until end of loop).
```

It is meant to return values corresponding to the values of other numbers in the same x or the same y coordinate (i.e. checks which numbers are not possibilities in a sudoku game). The position of booleans represent which numbers are possible- so if `possibilities[i][j][0] == false`, a value of 1 would not be possible in the spot [i][j] as there is a 1 value either in any other box with x = i or y = j.
Just wondering why it returns false for all values where j > 0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `possibilities[i][j] = defaultPossibilities;` If you do that you start overwriting the values in `defaultPossibilities`.

Comment: I believe that debugger was invented just for such situations.

Comment: @zapl Really? But I'm not changing the value of `defaultPossibilities` am I?

Comment: @zapl Thanks you're right. Why does the value of defaultPossibilities change?

Comment: What is `definite`? What is `num` for?

Comment: Really. It's a reference to an array. At the beginning `defaultPossibilities` refers to an array (a variable name is not the object, it just points to one). And after assigning it to `possibilities` you have 2 names for the same array.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultPossibilites` was being overwritten. Didn't realise that assigning the value of an array to a different array effectively just renames the array. Thanks to zapl